# How do you log the machine name via log4net?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I am using Log4Net with the AdoNetAppender to log messages from a simple systray application into a SQL Server 2005 database.

I want to log the machine name along with the log message because this application will be running on multiple machines and I need to know on which one the message originated.

But, I cannot find a way to expose this information via the log4net.Layout.PatternLayout that I am using with the appender.

Is there a way to log the machine name via log4net in this manner?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the pre-populated property `log4net:HostName`, for example:

```
<conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
```

This way you don't need to populate the MDC.

Comment: For future readers, I got my AdoNetAppender to work with this           <parameter name="workstation">
      <parameterName value="@workstation"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="256" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
    </parameter>

Comment: Future readers.  I ~think this comes from the FIELDS on this page : http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Core_LoggingEvent.htm

Answer (score 11):

you can create a parameter similar to the following:

```
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@machine" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%X{machine}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

Then add this line before writing to the log: `MDC.Set("machine", Environment.MachineName);`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I knew it must have been something simple.  Thanks.