# Including additional properties using PostSharp, Log4Net and Unity

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net, unity-container, postsharp

I have a WCF application which uses Unity (3.5.1404) for DI via Unity.Wcf (3.5.1404) and PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Log4Net (4.1.14) with Log4Net (2.0.3) for logging via UnityLog4NetExtension (1.1).

This all works exactly as expected and I get logging to both Event Log and SQL Server.

However, I can only see how to include the built in Log4Net properties - date, thread, logger, level, message, exception and location.

I want to add the server hostname and other custom properties into the logs.

I know that I can include extra properties in the logs via the Log4Net config - `%property{host}` - but I cannot work out where to place the code to do this via PostSharp's woven log code.

Is this possible?

Will I have to write a custom aspect to do this?

Comment: For this particular property, you may not need to - "[by default the log4net:HostName property is set to the name of machine on which the event was originally logged](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you log the machine name via log4net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162810/how-do-you-log-the-machine-name-via-log4net)

Comment: gah, that makes this a duplicate question!

Comment: @Shevek: kinda, but your question also included having custom properties as well that might not be available by default in log4net, so...

Comment: I've expanded the question slightly to include other properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way this could be done would be to place the code in your `Global.asax` like this.

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["host"] = System.Environment.MachineName;
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

The Application_Start function is called whenever your service is started.
Also note the call to `Configure` to ensure `log4net` is initialized properly.
You shouldn't have to modify anything else, well, besides your web.config of course.

Comment: Awesome! For Unity.WCF it actually goes in the Factory class but it works!